# Why do I no longer get desktop notifications from Google Calendar?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, google-calendar

I used to get desktop notifications for Google Calendar running in Chrome.

This is very useful to help me not to forget to join a Zoom meeting when working from home.

But for a while now I have not been receiving them.

I have my notifications settings in Google Calendar set like this:

[image: screenshot]

I hear the sound but I don't get a desktop notification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out Chrome did not have notifications enabled in macos settings:

[image: screenshot]

(not sure why I have two Google Chromes in this list)

Enabling this fixed it:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I had been changing notification settings for the Calendar app, not for Google Chrome. I have two Google Chromes, too; I'm suspecting that's because I'm using two Chrome profiles.

Comment: _"I'm suspecting that's because I'm using two Chrome profiles"_ ...that sounds quite likely, I also have two Chrome profiles (it's a shame we can't distinguish which is which in macOS settings though!)

Comment: I had to enable notifications for `Google Chrome Helper (Alerts)` as well to get it to work as expected. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75804760/2113226